# Is there a way to populate multiple DataGridViews with Columns from a SQL Server Table

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagridview

To clarify, I have a Form that has 4 different DataGridViews all of which are taking data from a SQL Server Stored Procedure that generates different tables.

I want to populate each DataGridView with data from each table in the Stored Procedure but i want to format it with the columns from the first Data Table in the Stored Procsdure

I hope this makes sense, any help would be appreciated

***Update***
To clarify, the way i populate is as follows

```
 Private Sub PopulateDGV()

    Dim sqlconn As New SqlConnection
    sqlconn.ConnectionString = myDatabase

    sqlconn.Open()
    Dim PopulateDGVSql As String = "sp.sql"
    Dim PopulateDGVcmd As New SqlCommand(PopulateDGVSql, sqlconn)
    Dim PopulateDGVAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter
    PopulateDGVAdapter.SelectCommand = PopulateDGVcmd
    PopulateDGVAdapter.Fill(DGVData) 'declared up top'

    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
    PopulateDGVAdapter.Fill(ds)
    sqlconn.Close()
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(1)
    DataGridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
End Sub
```

Again i want to keep the format for the columns on the first table but populate with the rows of a different slightly different table

Comment: please post what you tried and where you were struck?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with `format`?

Comment: What is the problem? `PopulateDGVAdapter.Fill(ds)` throws exception?  Add `PopulateDGVcmd.CommandType = StoredProcedure`.

Comment: The problem is i want the Columns from 1 table in the stored procedure for all the DataGridViews but the data from different tables

Comment: Couldn't you take the column headers from the stored procedure and create the columns headers for all of the other ones in code?

Comment: @codeMonger123 That sounds like an idea but i dont know how to, i cant find any information on doing this. Could you offer up some information?

Answer (score 0):

Well then code to get all the column names would be the below:

```
Dim name(DT.Columns.Count) As String
Dim i As Integer = 0
For Each column As DataColumn In DT.Columns
name(i) = column.ColumnName
i += 1
Next
```

This will get you all of the column names from your stored proc. For the other's you could then build the datatable from these column names and use DataReader to build the rows for the other stored procs. Or you could change the name of the already populated datatable's by doing something like the below:

```
   DT2.Columns(0).ColumnName = "newColumnName"
```

Comment: by the way - I think doing it in .net is the better way rather than SQL because if you change the column names in your first stored proc the .net will handle all of the rest. If you don't care about this you could just name the columns the same in all of the stored procs by Example:  select mycolumn as younewcolumnname from yourtable